# Cannot find kdc for realm

Tags: spnego

I am trying to do an authentication using spnego.
When  loginContext.login occurs i get the exception:
"Cannot fing KDC for realm realm.name"
I my krb5.conf i have:

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = realm-name.local
default_tkt_enctypes = aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
default_tgs_enctypes = aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
permitted_enctypes = aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc

[realms]
    REALM.INTERNAL = { 
        kdc = kdc.realm-name.local
        default_domain = realm-name.local
    }

[domain_realm]
    .REALM.INTERNAL = realm-name.local
    REALM.INTERNAL = realm-name.local
```